# How to change nested object value inside of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to change the state when a user clicks the delete button. Basically a nested object inside another nested object inside of an array

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    adminId: 2,
    roleId: 1,
    storeId: 1,
    createdAt: "2021-08-26T16:57:49.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-08-26T16:57:49.000Z",
    user: {
      id: 2,
      empId: 0,
      firstName: "Test1",
      lastName: "Test2",
      email: "test@test3.com",
      phone: "0900-786013",
      password: "$2b$10$XPxzZuzKLSl3Rm9YVk7AheZfLbvTNVV0jmo.NR/b0IJuFejW/hCFa",
      isActive: true,
      isDeleted: false,
      createdAt: "2021-08-26T16:57:49.000Z",
      updatedAt: "2021-08-30T07:34:38.000Z",
    },
  },
];
```

When the user clicks on the delete button the isDeleted value should be true. So far I have tried map with a map and also filter.

```
setStaff(
           data.map((item) => {
                return item.id === id
                  ? { ...item, item: (item.user.isDeleted = true) }
                  : item;
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying your state directly when you perform `item.user.isDeleted = true`,  which isn't how you should update state in React. Instead, you can set your `user` key in your new object to contain the same keys from `item.user` object by spreading that (`...item.user`) into a new object, and then overwrite the `isDeleted` property to `true`:

```
setStaff(data.map((item) => {
  return item.id === id
    ? { ...item, user: {...item.user, isDeleted: true }
    : item;
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution on jsfiddle and it is working correctly but on my react project it is not changing the field isDeleted to true which is displayed inside a table.

Comment: @InzamamBaig it's hard to tell what the issue would be without seeing more of your code, but try and debug it by ensuring that your code is running and that `id` is the correct type and value

Answer (score -1):

here try this.

```
setStaff(
       data.map((item) => {
            return item.id === id
              ? { ...item, user: {...item.user, isDeleted: true} }
              : item;
      })
```